# camelCase with lowercase initial with names

Tags: coding-style, camelcasing

Many coding standards recommend using camelCase with lowercase initial for variable and function names. What is the standard practice if the initial should be uppercase for "grammatical reasons", e.g., because it is a name? For instance, shall I write `KnuthPlassAlgorithm` or `knuthPlassAlgorithm`?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your language and who you ask.  Generally you "camelCase" local variables and "ProperCase" FunctionNames or ProtectedMemberVariables.  Often people use an underscore then camel case for _privateVariables.  If you want to not have to think about it and you are using VS and C# you should check out [stylecop](http://stylecop.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Yes, but the question is another: what do people do when something that they should `camelCase` has its own other reasons to start with a capital letter?

Comment: Goodness.  Sometimes I read what I think is there instead of what is written.  Everything I have worked on has followed the naming rules not grammar.